# How can i render the selected option using React_Select?

Tags: reactjs

I made a example in following:
I am new to React and i am using React Select

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';


const options = [
    { value: 'blues', label: 'Blues' },
    { value: 'rock', label: 'Rock' },
    { value: 'jazz', label: 'Jazz' },
    { value: 'orchestra', label: 'Orchestra' } 
];  
class DropDown3 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          selectOptions : [],
          id: "",
          name: ''
        }
      }
    handleChange = (selectedOption) =>
    {
        console.log("selected",selectedOption)
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
    };    
    render()
    {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;        

        return (
            <Fragment>
            <Select 
                options = {options} 
                onChange ={this.handleChange}
                value = {selectedOption}
                defaultValue={{ value: 'jazz', label: 'Jazz' }}            
            />
                <div>Hello you select {this.state.selectedOption}</div>
            </Fragment>
            
      );
    }
}


export default DropDown3;
```

what i want is to display what i have selected in the dropdown so that i can pass it to another component.
The abouve code didnt run everytime i choose a menu
and it run only i comment out the
"Hello you select {this.state.selectedOption}"
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `selectedOption` in the state, and when you update the state you should take the value of the `selectedOption` object.

```js
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import Select from "react-select";
    
    const options = [
      { value: "blues", label: "Blues" },
      { value: "rock", label: "Rock" },
      { value: "jazz", label: "Jazz" },
      { value: "orchestra", label: "Orchestra" }
    ];
    class DropDown3 extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          selectOptions: [],
          selectedOption: "",
          id: "",
          name: ""
        };
      }
      handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        console.log("selected", selectedOption);
        this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOption.value });
      };
      render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Select
              options={options}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={selectedOption}
              defaultValue={{ value: "jazz", label: "Jazz" }}
            />
            <div>Hello you select {this.state.selectedOption}</div>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default DropDown3;
```

Comment: thanks. you make my day ... But the selected option didnt place in the placeholder. This happen because changed from  this.setState({ selectedOption });
        ==> this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOption.value });

Comment: answer myself set selectedOption: "jazz"